# Azure Service Bus. AutoLockRenew

Tags: python, azureservicebus

I must be missing something. Trying to get basic AutoLockRenew code working but don't see renewal happening.

```
renew = AutoLockRenew(max_workers=4)
with queue_client.get_receiver() as messages:
    for message in messages:
        print(message.locked_until)
        renew.register(message, timeout=600)
        print(message.locked_until)
        break
```

locked_until doesn't change right away, which is, if I understood correctly, fine, but the problem is that it never changes. I keep monitoring it and lock never gets renewed and then message expires.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

(chiming in as one of the python service bus SDK maintainers)

You *seem* to be calling everything properly, but there are a few common things I'd double check.

1. Do you observe anything set in the message.auto_renew_error property before or after the message is observed to be expired?  If something went wrong during lock renewal it'd show up there.
2. Is your snippet representative where you are breaking out of the `with get_receiver` block before doing your work on the message? I'm assuming this is just for demonstration and you actually did whatever processing/renewal within the inner loop, but wanted to be sure, since that might cause odd symptoms, since the receiver would get closed when you exit the context manager.
3. Is your lock_duration on the queue/topic set to 5 minutes? (can check this in the azure portal)  We've seen potential clock-skew issues where right on the edge of max duration, the message isn't observed as needing to be renewed in sufficient time to renew it.
4. I'd mention you shouldn't need to specify max_workers, but it also shouldn't impact this.
5. If those don't turn up anything obvious, I'd drop a breadcrumb to [this sample](https://gist.github.com/KieranBrantnerMagee/e403c4f77f630d6664243dd52721fae3) I threw together for demonstrating autorenew with logging enabled.  With the uamqp and azure loggers, (and optionally setting debug=True in client creation to see ALL the lowest level details) you should be able to see any renew attempts that occur and if something is going wrong, it should be visible in those logs. (Or regardless, those logs would be integral to debugging this)

I'd mention that we try to be responsive [on Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus) (azure-sdk-for-python), that if this becomes a more involved investigation that isn't well suited to SO, to feel free to reach out there with issues.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great summary and example you've shared. I do have queue timeout at 5 minutes, so hitting #3 for sure. Enabled logging as per your exmaple and see 

Description: b"The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 240000 milliseconds and is closed by container '238165e016e44dcc949abe4d9613d60d_G8'."

There is the same message being investigated here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9917 , but my code is sync. Will open github questions. Thank you!

Comment: UPD: Looks like the same error is happening with 7.0 azure code, but this time - message.complete() works fine. Maybe related to this one https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9144

Comment: UPD2: Opened an issue against 0.50.3, just to have it documented, https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/11983

Comment: Thanks Bob; responded back in-thread, but to quickly echo the advice I gave there here for posterity:    

1. 5 minute lock_duration can expose you to clock-skew-based failures at the edge.
2. >4 minute lock_duration can fail due to service-side idle-timeout, we're looking to address this issue for our 7.0 release.    

As a workaround, using a lock_duration of ~3.5 minutes or less is advised, and not adjusting the renew_period of Autorenewer from the default (just in case you were, since those two functionalities can interact)